# In python, how to make a conditional of multiple statements into a shorthand line like a ternary operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can a turn this code into a shorthand line of code? is it possible at all?

I would like the same purpose of the code, but with the least amount of lines possible

```
 inpt = input('Age: ')
    age = int(inpt)


if age <= 10:
    print('Kid')
elif age > 10 <= 20:
    print('Teen')    
elif age > 20:
    print('Adult')
```

Comment: `age >10 <=20` doesn't do what you think. It expands to the equivalent of `age > 10 and 10 <= 20`. Which means your `Adult` case is never reached, you only print `Kid` or `Teen`. You want `10 < age <= 20`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try:

```
text = 'kid' if age <= 10 else 'teen' if age <= 20 else 'adult'
```

Example:

```
age = 4
text = 'kid' if age <= 10 else 'teen' if age <= 20 else 'adult'
print(text)
age = 12
text = 'kid' if age <= 10 else 'teen' if age <= 20 else 'adult'
print(text)
age = 25
text = 'kid' if age <= 10 else 'teen' if age <= 20 else 'adult'
print(text)
```

Output:

```
kid
teen
adult
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to shorten it to:

```
age = int(input('Age: '))

print('Kid' if age <= 10 else 'Teen' if age <= 20 else 'Adult')
```

That said, unless you're doing one-liners for fun, I'd stick to your original code, after fixing the test for `Teen` and just making the `Adult` case a plain `else` (no need to retest `> 20` since the previous cases eliminated the other possibilities).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be that suggested but you can try out something using `short circuiting`. I personally think this is more readable(not for your example) but at the cost of extra comparisons.

```
input = input('Age: ')
age = int(input)


age <= 10 and print('Kid')

age > 10 and age <= 20 and print('Teen')

age > 20 and print('Adult')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
age = int(input('Age: '))
print('Adult' if age > 20 else 'Kid' if age <= 10 else 'Teen')
```

In Python you have a ternary operator:

```
a if condition else b
```